# Does a repository at Github track who has cloned and pulled it where?

Tags: git, github

1. Can a repository at Github track who has cloned it to where and who
   has pulled from it to where?

   Assume the repository is private, and then it makes sense that its
   owner might want to do that.
2. What about a git repository not on Github, i.e. can a git repository
   in general track who has cloned and pulled it to where?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a purely GitHub based repository, you can look at the network section in order to get an idea of who has forked your repository.  Have a look at the network graph for this repository as an example:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake/network

**NOTE:** This only gives you the most basic overview of people who have forked your repository, people who have simply cloned the repo locally won't show up on this list.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherent to Git that does this.

The functionality of a Git repository can be extended using ["hooks"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). These are scripts placed in the .git directory that are executed before or after various operations. It is with these hooks that servers like GitHub and GitLab do "extra" things, such as track the number of clones of a repository.

Comment: Thanks. Can a repository on Github track who have cloned and pulled from it and where it is cloned and pulled to? This is more than just the number of clones of it.

Comment: Can they? Sure, they run the servers, they know the IP addresses connecting to them. Do they? Not as far as I know.